# Can we implement a placeholder in npm scripts and replace it using the npm command?

Tags: node.js, testing, npm, testcafe, npm-scripts

I have a npm script

```
"scripts": {
"test:chrome": "set DEV_MODE=staging& npx testcafe \"chrome --start-fullscreen\" automation_suite/tests"
}
```

i want to replace the `DEV_MODE=staging` to `DEV_MODE=dev` instead of writing multiple scripts.

something like

`npm run test:chrome --dev` should replace the `staging` to `dev` and execute the script

Comment: No, you can't do that. Just set the env var outside, for nix it would be `DEV_MODE=dev npm run test:chrome`.

Comment: you can create separate scripts for both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write some command with a default value, users can override if they need on passing another argument. samples:

```
"scripts": {
    "test:chrome": "export DEV_MODE=${DEV_MODE:-staging} && echo $DEV_MODE"
  },
```

**Run:**

```
$npm run test:chrome
#Output: staging

$DEV_MODE=dev npm run test:chrome
#Output: dev
```

This will at least ease ur way of writing.

Comment: will the above code work in the Windows environment using `set`?
`"scripts": {
    "test:chrome": "set DEV_MODE=${DEV_MODE:-staging} && echo $DEV_MODE"
  }`
seems like not working when I am using set

Comment: use git bash, or find alternate in PowerShell, i don't have window laptop to try :(